# Intersect method error when changing work sheet

Tags: vba, excel, intersect

Whenever a user is editing a cell and switching the sheet while editing, the following error message appears:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Intersect' of object '_Global' failed
```

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'If Changes Intersect with Data Inventory Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Range("E6"), Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row))) Is Nothing Then
         If (TypeName(Target.Value) = "String") Then 'Distinction between pressing button and modifying process name
            If Target.Value <> ChangeTrack Then 'Prevents duplicate check from being called if Process name stays the same
                Call generate_ID(Target.Value, Target, sh)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Sorry for the nested if statements (for some reason it doesn't work if I link up multiple statements with the 'And' operator inbetween?)

I think it has to do with range comparisons between different sheet, that lead to a crash in the Intersect method but I also tried to explicitly define the Range with sh.Range(...) with no luck.

Comment: `I think it has to do with range comparisons between different sheet`. Yes you are somewhat correct. You need to `Explicitly` reference your objects.

Comment: did you try `If Not Intersect(Target, sh.Range(sh.Range("E6"), sh.Range("E" & sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row))) Is Nothing Then`?

Comment: If ChangeTrack is a string, you shouldn't have to determine the data type of Target before you make a comparison. I would be more worried about the two most common conflict areas: a) when Target is more than a single cell and b) when changing a value runs Workbook_SheetChange on top of itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a ThisWorkbook Workbook_SheetChange trigger but failing to take advantage of the *Sh* worksheet parameter being fed into it.

Additionally, a worksheet change will always occur within the worksheet's .UsedRange.

`generate_ID(Target.Value, Target, sh)` seems redundant. If you pass Target as a parameter then its value and its parent worksheet come along with it.

```
private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'If Changes Intersect with Data Inventory Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, sh.Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then
         If (TypeName(Target.Value) = "String") Then 'Distinction between pressing button and modifying process name
            If Target.Value <> ChangeTrack Then 'Prevents duplicate check from being called if Process name stays the same
                Call generate_ID(Target.Value, Target, sh)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm guessing that ChangeTrack is some sort of public var.